# How to save an object, using Hibernate as persistence, with a foreign key using Jackson?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I would like to apologize in advance if this question has been answered before.

Please note that the project is using Spring Boot, Jackson and Hibernate.

Anyway, I forked a project by [Jasenko Hadziomeragic](http://jasenkoh.blogspot.com/2014/11/java-restful-web-services-with-spring.html). I wanted to know how he was able to save an object, in Jasenko's project, the Product object. In this project, the Product object looks like this (please note that I removed parts of the code to focus on the foreign key) :

```
@JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
@NotNull
private Long member_id;
```

I can save a new record by using this JSON:

```
{
  "name" : "Product 2",
  "member_id" : "1"
}
```

This works but from what I have scoured in the internet, it's better to use this instead:

```
public class Product {

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="member_id")
private Member member;

/* A getter/setter for the memeber id*/
public Long getMember_id() {
    return this.member.getId();
}

public void setMember_id(Long member_id) {
    this.member.setId(member_id);
}
}
```

I tried to save a new record with the same json above, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.jersey.representations.Product.setMember_id(Product.java:100)
```

Here's a link to my [github](https://github.com/franciszabala/spring-boot-jersey-hibernate) that contains modified codes.

I also checked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195380/jackson-seemingly-not-persisting-bidirectional-relationship-managed-by-hibernate) that is similar to my concern. But what it does it first it sends a select query first to populate the Member object. But that means before I save a record, I have to request another select statement. It's a bit of an overhead, isn't it?

**UPDATE**
I added this code in the constructor:

```
public Product() {
    this.member = new Member();
}
```

I did fix my issue but is this the correct way of dealing with my concern?

**UPDATE 2**

What I am trying to avoid is sending this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Derp",
        "currency": "599",
        "regularPrice": 1203,
        "discountPrice": 59,
        "member": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Paul",
            "lastName": "Andrews",
            "email": "myemail@email.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Another product ",
       "currency": "909",
        "regularPrice": 1203,
        "discountPrice": 59,
        "member": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Paul",
            "lastName": "Andrews",
            "email": "myemail@email.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Another product 1",
        "currency": "909",
        "regularPrice": 1203,
        "discountPrice": 59,
        "member": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Paul",
            "lastName": "Andrews",
            "email": "myemail@email.com"
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, the member keeps repeating whereas I can just send the memberId.

[Another link to a similar question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275538/rest-api-and-hibernate-how-to-add-a-new-record-with-foreign-key?noredirect=1#comment54357501_33275538)

Comment: You have probably NPE because your `member` field to which you are trying to set `member_id` value is not initialized. Firstly you have to create `member` and then assign him id.

Comment: But what if the member already exists? Won't that create another member record?

Comment: So you have to find out if it already exists. IMO the way you do it is wrong. Why do you want to have method which is setting id for the member in Product class? In Product class you should set the whole `Member` object or you should have `Long memberId` field and set your `member_id` value to this field.

Comment: I'll update my question to answer your concerns.

Comment: The better way would be to either create `new Member()` if it doesn't exist or assign existing member from database something like `dao.findMemberById(memberId);`

Comment: But that's a severe overhead. What if member table is so huge that a query for a single row returns in 5 seconds. But you have to save 2000 products with different memberIds. That is going to take a lot of time where as simple insert statement is faster.

Comment: @FrancisZabala You can use a fake Member with only an id field setted. And set this member to Product because of you need a Member foreign key  only. You don't need save members, only products.

Comment: @v.ladynev hello again. Yes, I tried that by adding new Member() in the Product constructor. Is that the best practice or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @FrancisZabala Hello :) No. It is a bad one.  [See this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-examples/simply-console/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/persistent/User.java#L73) for adding products to Member. If you want to deal without adding products to Member: You need an id of Member, create Member, set id, and set Member  to Product...than save Product.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to learn Hibernate using a simply console application with `Model` and `Product` persistents. You don't need `@JoinColumn` for `products` but `@OneToMany` with `mappedBy` property. You can refer [User](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-examples/simply-console/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/persistent/User.java#L68) as an analogue of `Member` and [UserFriend](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-examples/simply-console/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/persistent/UserFriend.java#L33) as `Product`. In every `Product` you need to have foreign key to `User` — add products to member [this way](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-examples/simply-console/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/persistent/User.java#L73). For experiments you can use [this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/tree/master/fluent-hibernate-examples) or [this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate-mysql).

Comment: Ok. I am going to check this out. I have to check my work again. I was so burned by this I forgot why abandoned this.

Comment: @FrancisZabala You can stream your work [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/). It will be funny. My stream [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/ladynev/).

Comment: @FrancisZabala yeah :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I finally got to make it work. I don't know where to pinpoint but I can definitely say that it's not JSON marshalling by Jackson issue.

Here's my solution:

First, I can't find a solution but to add this to class that has the foreign key:

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    public Product() {
        this.member = new Member();
    }

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="blargh")
    private Member member;
    /** Jackson can't instantiate and object automatically so you have to help it **/
    /** By creating the object right after Product is initialzed by some other code **/
    public Long getMobileNum() {
        return this.member.getMobileNum();
    }

    public void setMobileNum(Long mobileNum) {
        this.member.setMobileNum(mobileNum);
    }
}
```

Next step to look for it the Id annotation in the other class.

```
@Entity
public class Member {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Long mobileNum;
}
```

I intentionally made the annotations wrong to prove a point. In the Product class, it's foreign key that links it to the Member class is mobileNum. If mobileNum or any foreign key is annotated with @Id, Hibernate will bind it properly and won't have any issues saving the object.

But if the foreign key is not annotated with @Id, Hibernate (even if Jackson has properly mapped the JSON to the object), **it will not bind it properly resulting in null values**. *Google search keyword: object references an unsaved transient instance*

Adding Cascade is not a good solution in my opinion as it just creates more records in the Member class. It will keep on creating EVEN if the record already exists! (Trying putting a unique constraint on mobileNum and remove the @Id annotation.

Overall, this week in Hibernate has really burned me out. If you're a developer who had experience in optimizing an existing SQL and just want to turn it into code, stay away from Hibernate. Use MyBatis, even if it has a lot of boilerplate, it's much more satisfying to create your SQL by hand than by Hibernate.